# Insert Custom Objects into a List of Custom Objects

Tags: flutter, list, listview

I have a ListView of custom objects.

I'd like to insert a variety of other custom objects into my list.

So the goal would be something like this:

```
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectB
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectC
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectA
CustomObjectC
```

I may have some that I want to go to a specific row, whereas others may be every nth row.

The problem I see is I have `List<dynamic> objects`, but if I do something like:

```
objects.insert(
    3,
    CustomObjectB(),
);
```

I get an error as `CustomObjectB` is NOT a `CustomObjectA`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects you add to ListView (ex. CustomObjectA) are Widgets, then List objects update it to List.

Or you can use List but if they are widgets List is required